# design ui like solar system in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to design an android UI just like solar system. Where the center holds a main logo and other options like settings logo, etc will be in the position of the planets.is it possible with the relative layout ? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using [`CircleLayout`](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout), a free and open source component. `RelativeLayout` is rather suitable for use in rectangular compositions.

Comment: Ok, I understand but how to draw the circle line connecting all the points. this layout put the items in a circular manner but the its doesn't draw any circular line.

Comment: Just put it the `CircleLayout` into a `FrameLayout` together with an `ImageView` that contains an appropriate image or drawable.

Comment: but my items will be dynamic...your suggestion holds for static items but is it also holds dynamic items?

Comment: Yes, why not. Any layout can be filled programmatically.

Comment: If it answered your question, please accept this answer by clicking the check mark to the left.